# how to use span:not() to avoid span with certain

Tags: html, jquery, css, styling

I would like to apply the following stying to all my span tags, except for those containing the text 'dontwant'

```
 span:not("dontwant"){
    font-weight: inherit;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0rem black);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black
  }
```

here is the span I would like to avoid:
dontwant

UPDATE posted in a comment: What about using jquery to hide that element with that text? Is that possible?

Comment: That’s not possible, because [there’s no CSS selector for matching text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text). You need to identify them with something selectable, like a class.

Comment: Do you mean containing a *class* "dontwant" or the actual text? you cannot select text using CSS, if that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: @user998548 You asked if jQuery could be used in a comment on another answer - l've edited the question to add the `jquery` tag and a included a jQuery solution in my answer that can also be used in angular - let us know if that works or if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

As we mentioned, **CSS doesn’t have a selector that lets you match text**. You could **do it in CSS** by adding classes to all of the elements that contain the text you don’t want to style, but that requires the HTML to be changed.

You ask in a comment if this could be done using jQuery - it can, using a combination of the `contains` and `not` selectors.

**Using jQuery** also means you don’t don’t have to change the existing HTML.

The easiest way is to first create a CSS class with the styles to apply, e.g.

```
.shadow {
    font-weight: inherit;
    filter: drop-shadow (0px 0px 0rem black);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black
}
```

Now you can use JQuery to select all spans that do not contain “dontwant” and add your class to them, like this:

```
$('span:not(:contains("dontwant"))').addClass('shadow');
```

You just add this line to your `$(document).ready(function()`

**Working Snippet**:

```js
    $('span:not(:contains("dontwant"))').addClass('shadow');
```

```css
.shadow {
    font-weight: inherit;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0rem black);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This is a span I <span>dontwant</span> to add <span>shadow</span>.</p>
<p>This is <span>another</span> span I <span>dontwant</span> to add <span>shadow</span>.</p>
```

You can include this in Angular in the `ngOnInit` function, e.g.:

```
public ngOnInit(){
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('span:not(:contains("dontwant"))').addClass('shadow');
   });
}
```